# Laravel Scheduler fires 1 hour earlier

Tags: laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan, totem

Since summertime change in Europe/London, my Laravel Tasks firing 1 hour earlier. I use the [laravel-totem](https://github.com/codestudiohq/laravel-totem) package in [Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8) framework.

The timezone correctly set in app/config/app.php to 'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
SSHd into the server and checked the current time in tinker and it is showing the correct time. 
Totem has its own config file, but there is no reference to the timezone settings. Also, totem. index page showing all tasks where the "Next run time" is the correct one, but the "Last run" time showing 1 hour earlier.

My settings: 
config/app.php

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/London',
```

[Totem index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpyzi.png)

I hope anyone could point me the right direction. I'm sure I've just missed here something. 
Thank you

**Update**: Created an issue ticket on totem's repo. https://github.com/codestudiohq/laravel-totem/issues/160

Comment: Is it possible you're confusing Europe/London with UTC/GMT somewhere? They're not the same

Comment: #Evert Apologies for the late reply. I don't think that's the case as the database showing the correct "run_at" time. Just triggered the command from Totem and checked the timestamp in the database. Whilst the database showing "2019-04-28 19:03:38", Totem shows "2019-04-28 18:03:38". 
Other entries, e.g. When I create a new user or new record, it has the correct timestamp. I might need to create an issue  on the Totem's repo, but I'd like to troubleshoot to make sure the problem is not on my end. 
Thanks